# Use XAML DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" in Desktop App (not UWP)

Tags: wpf, xaml

What is required to use x:DeferLoadStrategry="Lazy" in XAML? All the documentation just mentions it as being "new to Windows 10" but I haven't been able to get it to work in my WPF Desktop application.

When I attempt to use the attribute I get the message "The attribute DeferLoadStrategy from the XAML namespace is not defined." Is this attribute only available to UWP apps (not desktop apps)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`x:DeferLoadStrategy` is not available in WPF. It is a UWP feature only.